# POST request not accepting my GraphQL input

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, facebook-graph-api, graphql

How do I get this post request to work:

```
{"query":"user(id: "jack") { getDetails { edges { node { name } } } name, description }"}
```

Even if I use single quotes it still does not work as it is an invalid JSON string.

The authorizations tokens are fine (bearer token)

I am using this site to [test](https://reqbin.com/) the POST request

Comment: you need to escape the double quotes in the id `\"jack\"`

Comment: @about14sheep Still doesn't work, but if I use a simple query without any quotes it works fine. It gives me a `parse error`

Comment: @about14sheep `Parse error on \"user\" (IDENTIFIER) at [1, 1]",`

Comment: escaping will make it valid json, I can post in that site you posted and it doesn't get an error. If there is an issue in your server i would need to see that code to be able to help

Comment: @about14sheep I just tried it again with a simple query and it doesn't work anymore. Is this the right thing to put in `content`, `{"query": "test"}`? I get the same parse error

Comment: is it set too application/json in the dropdown above?

Comment: @about14sheep Yep, I don't get a parse error if I set it to `custom` but then the query on the API Endpoints side is invalid

Comment: I dont know about this site you are using but it shouldnt be showing a parse error for `{"query": "test"}` at all. Maybe try reloading or using an application like postman or insomnia

Comment: @about14sheep Fixed it using another site, not sure what's up with that one

Comment: did query work? if escaping solved your problem ill add an answer and we can close out this question

Comment: @about14sheep Yep query was fine and escaped it. Thanks for the help, not sure how to close

Comment: I have added the solution that solved this for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes in your query to make it valid JSON.

Try:

```
{"query":"user(id: \"jack\") { getDetails { edges { node { name } } } name, description }"}
```